# Facebook custom story and object timeline headings

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-stream-story

I have created a custom object on my website for my Facebook app to use. I currently have everything working correctly with the exception of the heading when the story is displayed on the timeline. For example, the story reads:

```
"John computed a personal analytics"
```

when I would like it to read as:

```
"John computed personal analytics"
```

There are settings for the story where I have changed this to read correctly but the changes are not reflected when the story is actually generated. The story even makes the correct preview when I ask for a preview on the developer site. Is there a piece of meta-data or some setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing Facebook to refresh that data? Maybe it still displays the old one from before the change. 
I believe it was possibly within the object debugger.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

So if you have the URL http:www.example.com/index.php, you simply attach a `?fbrefresh=[somerandomcharacters]` here and it should do the trick.

I have to say that only worked sometimes for me too, sometimes Facebook can be a bit stubborn.

Comment: No posts were created before the change was made. I have used the debugger for other purposes but it does not show what the post would look like on a user's timeline; it only shows the meta-data from the page. Since the heading (not the title) is not changeable through meta-data, it is not shown. Thanks for the suggestion though.